# How To prevent copied session cookies being used

Tags: session, cookies, c#-6.0

This has been asked before, but I haven't seen anything posted about it in years, and I'm running into the problem now.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log into my site (C# 6, angularjs, .Net Framework 4.8)
2. Once logged in, use Cookie Editor to export the session cookies in the browser (using Chrome in this instance, but that doesn't matter.)
3. Log out
4. Using Cookie editor, import the copied session cookies.
5. Refresh the page... voila - I'm logged back in.

So, my code for logging out does all the "get rid of stored cookies" things it should: loop through all the cookies and expire them; clear the Request.Cookies; Abandon the Session; Clear the Session; RemoveAll on the session.

But when you paste that dang **.ASPXAUTH** cookie back into the browser... whammo. Logged in.

I'm not sure how to prevent this, and could really use the help.

Comment: **.ASPXAUTH** is not the session cookie. It's the authentication cookie. If you don't have extra logic to validate it, it's all you have.

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Right, but it's created by Forms Auth, not by our code - is there a way to prevent copying and pasting the thing? I've set my code to kill it, but cookie editor will let a person just pasted it right back in place.

Comment: There's no way around that. The server only knows about the HTTP request its receiving. How do you propose avoiding that?

Comment: @PKD did you got the solution for this? I also facing the same scenerio.

Comment: Sadly, no. Or at least not in a friendly fashion. It looks like we'll be shifting to tokenized logins, and relying on non-public means of temporary storage (which is better, honestly, but not easier).